# Matlab mcc Warning "Adding path ... to Compiler path instance"

Tags: matlab, mcc

I'm compiling my matlab .m functions (and mex files) to run as a standalone program on a Linux server. In the end, I manage to compile all files and even run them, although in the process I do get some warnings:

```
Warning: Adding path "input_folder1" to Compiler path instance.
Warning: Adding path "input_folder2" to Compiler path instance.
Warning: Adding path "input_folder3" to Compiler path instance.
```

**Basically, my question is what is causing these warnings and how can I avoid them?**

**And, can I run into trouble if I move this standalone program to a different server?**

The mcc line that is causing these warnings is:

```
mcc -m -d output_folder -I input_folder1 -I input_folder2 -I input_folder3 -a mex_file1.mexa64 -a mex_file2.mexa64 MainScriptFile.m SubFunction1.m SubFunction2.m SubFunction3.m
```

Answer (score 6):

These warnings are caused by a missing path. If you want to shut them off, you can either disable them using `warning off` or add the `input_folder`s to the Compiler path before compiling. But since mcc does that anyway (and displays a warning), you can safely ignore them.

Basically, they're just mcc telling you *"Couldn't you have done that to start with? Now I'll have to do it myself..."*.

I can't answer your second question the way it is worded, so I'll have to go with this: You will not run into trouble **caused by these warnings** or any implications. If you do run into trouble, it's for a different reason.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! I thought that the `-I input_folders` part in the mcc statement was adding these paths to the Compiler path, so I was confused by the warnings. Could you indicate what the correct way is to add these paths to the compiler path before compiling?

Comment: It is indeed strange. Are you using the stand-alone version of the Compiler or the Matlab toolbox version? Maybe it just displays the warnings by default. Have you tried using the `-v` option to see when exactly the warnings come?

Comment: @Dennis: After some research, it seems this warning is always displayed and is actually more of a notice to let you know what happpens.

Comment: @scenia seems the case indeed: building the exact same project using mcc from Matlab R2018a we do not get those warnings anymore - so this was probably rather a bug in mcc, because we would get those warnings for a directory which actually was being added to the path